# Сортировка по алфавиту sqlite3 не срабатывает

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка, sqlite3

Понадобилось отсортировать таблицу по одному столбцу (type), в алфавитном порядке, но принт как выводил в разброс, так и выводит. Хотя код пишу так-же как в гайд-статье, подскажите пожалуйста что не так

```
import sqlite3
with sqlite3.connect('Frutis.db') as db:
    query = """
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fruits(
        type TEXT,
        sort TEXT
        )
        """
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO fruits(type, sort) VALUES(?, ?)", ('Яблоко', 'Сладкий'))
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO fruits(type, sort) VALUES(?, ?)", ('Апельсин', 'Кислый'))
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO fruits(type, sort) VALUES(?, ?)", ('Слива', 'Сладкая'))
    db.commit()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM fruits")
    print(cursor.fetchall())
    print("-------------------------------------------------------")
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM fruits ORDER BY type ASC")
    db.commit()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM fruits")
    print(cursor.fetchall())
```

Заранее спасибо за ответ

Comment: `cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM fruits")` — вот в этом запросе нет никакой сортировки

Comment: @andreymal, ааа, я думал ORDER BY перезапишет нынешнюю таблицу отсортированной, я понял, спасибо